# How do i use speedtest-cli or any alternative in python script instead of command line?

Tags: python, windows

I would like to use speedtest-cli or any alternative in my python program to know my internet download and upload speed.

Am using windows for this and speedtest-cli seems to work well in the command line but don't know how to use it in my python script.

Comment: You want to find your internet speed from inside a python script?

Comment: You can use `subprocess.Popen` to do this as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [speedtest-cli](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speedtest-cli/) module directly, as long as you install it into your current directory:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py
```

Now in your other file you can use it as you would any other module:

```
import speedtest

speedtester = speedtest.Speedtest()
speedtester.get_best_server()

print(speedtester.download())
```

You can also use it as a one-liner:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py \
    | python
```